# Locate variable of my prototype

Tags: javascript

I have an object in Javascript:

```
function MyObject(aField) {
    this.field = aField;
}

MyObject.prototype.aFunction = function() {
    return this.field;
}
```

Then

```
var anInstance = new MyObject("blah");
var s = anInstance.aFunction();
```

this works fine, but if I pass the function to another function:

```
callLater(anInstance.aFunction);
```

I don't control `callLater` and it's minified, but it seems that it's calling `aFunction` using `call()` or `apply()`. Therefore, `this` points to another object and `field` is undefined.

What's the best practice to avoid this situation I'm facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you lost the value of `this` Try this instead:

```
callLater(function() { anInstance.aFunction() });
```

Explaination, Think of it this way

```
function MyObject(aField) {
    this.field = aField;
}
function MyObject2(aField) {
    this.field = aField;
}
MyObject.prototype.aFunction = someFunct;
MyObject2.prototype.aFunction = someFunct;
```

Now what does `someFunct` belong to?

Well try doing `MyObject.prototype.aFunction === MyObject2.prototype.aFunction` it'll be true!

You see the problem Therefore it needs to be called from the class and not just referenced by value.