# Javascript 'undefined' variable when using async.map on prototype functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to use the fantastic [async module](https://github.com/caolan/async) to write some nice Javascript code for NodeJS. I've got an array of values and I want to call a particular function on each value and to accumulate the results in an array: I use async.map for this. Unfortunately, if the function I try to call is a prototype function of my class, it fails to read variable values.

**Example**
This is a test "class" I've defined.

```
var async = require('async');

function ClassA() {
    this.someVar = 367;
};

ClassA.prototype.test1 = function(param, callback) {
    console.log('[' + param + ']The value in test is: ' + this.someVar);
    callback(null, param + this.someVar);
};

ClassA.prototype.test2 = function() {
    var self = this;

    async.map([1,3,4,5], (self.test1), function(err, result){
        if (err) {
            console.log('there was an error')
        } else {
            console.log('Result is: ' + result)
        }
    })
};

module.exports = new ClassA();
```

And this is how I use it

```
testclass.test1(1, function(err, data){});
testclass.test2();
```

That's the output:

```
[1]The value in test is: 367
[1]The value in test is: undefined
[3]The value in test is: undefined
[4]The value in test is: undefined
[5]The value in test is: undefined
Result is: NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
```

As you can see the output obtained through `test2` which makes use of `async.map` cannot access the `this.someVar` variable.

**Questions**
I am definitely missing something here. Can somebody point me to the error and explain why it is not working? I would expect 367 to appear in place of those undefined. I think the problem is related to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12012911/locate-variable-of-my-prototype), but I can't seem to find a solution for my use case.

Thanks for reading and sorry for the length of the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert in that library (in fact, I have never used it).

But looking at this [section](https://github.com/caolan/async#binding-a-context-to-an-iterator) in its docs, I think that the problem lies in the fact that what you are passing to the iterator is the function itself, but async calls that function in it's own context, meaning that the `this` parameter inside your function isn't the one you are expecting.

Try following the docs advice (using bind) to avoid this pitfall.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful advice! I was able to make it work by modifying the map line to `async.map([1,3,4,5], this.test1.bind(this), function(err, result)`!